# Binding to Entity Object in WPF (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a `TextBox` bound to the Entity Framework object `User`. Works fine. But now, when I change the `User` object to the new `User.CreateUser(0, ...)` or `null`, `TextBox` doesn't change.

Why?

Best regards, James

Comment: I think you need to give some more info. What is meant by "changing `User` object to <...>'? You can't really *change* an object, you can assign the reference, call method, etc. What does `CreateUser` do? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pls post your binding and your datacontext, otherwise its hard to say whats wrong. i could just assume that INotifyPropertyChanged is not implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that the binding hooks in at right level, not all changes are observed by the binding engine, e.g. if you only specify the `Source` that is identical to assigning the object referenced by the source, the binding will look for the `PropertyChanged` event on the source to update itself if you bind to a property using the `Path`, however it will never know if the source is swapped out.

If you bind to the User using the path this is not your issue, just what exactly is wrong is not inferable (for me, that is) from your question alone, you should probably post some code.